# how can i give margin between two column with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, margin

I want to place a `margin` of `10px` between two columns in Bootstrap. I have 2 `div`s, one to the left and one to the right.

#### Current:

[image]

#### Goal:

[image]

#### Code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="shadow col-md-9">
       Content
   </div>
   <div class="shadow col-md-3">
       Content      
   </div>
</div>
```

*shadow class give border color.

Comment: I usually nest within a column to achieve that effect.

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Comment: I answered this and in the future, the correct tag is twitter-bootstrap or twitter-bootstrap-3, not bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-9">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-11 shadow">left div</div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 shadow">right div</div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the quick version. Realistically, you could add whatever class in place of col-md-11/12. See http://www.bootply.com/EdpTvNuKW5. Because it's nested inside, it will keep the properties of the parent in relation to responsive utilities.

Comment: As mentioned, you can change the class to whatever you want. Name a class (instead of `col-md-11`) something like `ten` and then use `.ten{margin-right:10px;} `. http://www.bootply.com/m6dKE64g0D

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row"> 
<div class="shadow col-md-9"> left div  </div> 
<div class="col-md-3"> 
<div class="shadow">right div</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use media queries and an inner div inside the column you want 10px margin.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ripiz/1/

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 primary">
   Content
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
   <div class="inner">
    Side
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.primary,
.sidebar {
    border: 1px solid #777; /* your .shadow classes go here */
    font-size: 150%; /* demo only */
}

@media (min-width:992px) { 
    .sidebar {
        padding-left: 10px;
        border: 0px; /* remove shadow classes here */
    }

    .sidebar .inner {
        border: 1px solid #777;  /* add shadow classes here */
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
}
```